kubuntu 24 crashes/ hangs up randomly
i installed kubuntu 24 (dual booting along with windows 11) just over a month or two ago. at the moment it is updated to the latest stable version (or so far i understood! uname -r returns 6.8.0-45-generic).
for some reason, it was started crashing randomly at least two weeks ago. each time, i had to force close by long-pressing the power button. changing tty/ restarting plasma session didn't help.
along with that, i noticed another weird issue. at every power_off/ reboot/ hanging-up-during-reboot_or_power_off, the following message pops up ubuntu noble numbat (development branch). a screenshot is attached for reference.
while looking for my sources (ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list*) list. found the
followings.
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 17 07:24 /etc/apt/sources.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  258 Apr 25 15:41 /etc/apt/sources.list~

/etc/apt/sources.list.d:
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 16 15:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Aug 17 07:24 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  190 Sep 16 15:07 google-chrome.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  105 Sep 16 15:07 mozilla.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1785 Sep 16 15:07 qbittorrent-team-ubuntu-qbittorrent-stable-noble.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  202 Sep 16 15:07 ubuntu-esm-apps.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  206 Sep 16 15:07 ubuntu-esm-infra.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2623 Sep 16 15:07 ubuntu.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  204 Sep 16 15:07 vscode.list

not sure about why the sources.list is empty. the content of sources.list~ is as follows.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble-updates main restricted universe multiverse

full disclaimer, i tinker a lot with KDE desktop. i am not sure, if it had any anything to do with that, as i don't understand, which journal should i look for. it's an hp probook 450 g9 (i5 12 gen cpu, 31g ram, 1tb nvme ssd).
this has become a serious headache, as the issue is becoming more prevalent. kindly requesting for your assistance in any way if you can, or at least, let me know, if i should go for re-installation/ switching OS. thank you.
